# Is there a better flow for returning the response?

Tags: php

So I have the `getSessionNamespace` method in the below class in which I am trying to return different scenarios but one json response. So my solution is to store the required `message` and `status code` in a response array and vary it depending on the situation.

Is there a cleaner more obvious method?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\auth\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\auth\Service\AuthGroupService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

/**
 * Class SessionController
 * @package Drupal\my_moduke\Controller
 */
class SessionController extends ControllerBase
{
    /**
     * @var AuthGroupService
     */
    protected static $authGroupService;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        self::$authGroupService = $container->get('auth.auth_group');
        return parent::create($container);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param bool    $internal
     *
     * @return mixed|JsonResponse
     */
    public function getSessionNamespace(Request $request, $internal = false)
    {
        try {
            if (!$request->headers->has('host')) {
                throw new \HttpHeaderException('Header \'host\' not found.');
            }

            $host = $request->headers->get('host');

            // Query datastore for the authGroup data for the given host.
            $result = $this->getAuthGroupData($host);
            $configId = \Drupal::config('auth.settings')->get('DS5.auth_group_id');

            if (!$this->allowedAccess($configId, $result['authGroupId'])){
                throw new HttpException(403, 'Not allowed.');
            }

            $response = [
                'result' => $result,
                'status' => 200
            ];
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            $response = [
                'result' => 'The endpoint responded with a ' . $e->getCode(),
                'status' => $e->getCode()
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = [
                'result' => $e->getMessage(),
                'status' => $e->getStatusCode()
            ];
        }

        if ($internal) {
            return $response['result'];
        }

        $jsonResponse = new JsonResponse($response['result'], $response['status']);

        if (!$_COOKIE[$response['result']['cookieName']] && $response['status'] === 200) {
            $this->createSessionCookie($jsonResponse, $response['result']);
        }

        return $jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * @param JsonResponse $response
     * @param array        $values
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    private function createSessionCookie(JsonResponse $response, array $values)
    {
        $dateTime = new \DateTime('+'. $values['sessionTimeToLiveSeconds'] .' seconds');

        $sessionCookie = new Cookie(
            $values['cookieName'],
            session_id(),
            $dateTime,
            '/',
            $values['domain']
        );

        $response->headers->setCookie($sessionCookie);
    }

    /**
     * @param $configId
     * @param $authGroupId
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function allowedAccess($configId, $authGroupId)
    {
        return $configId === $authGroupId;
    }

    /**
     * @param $host
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getAuthGroupData($host)
    {
        // Fetch from authGroup datastore endpoint.
        return self::$authGroupService->fetchAuthGroupData($host);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this generally looks pretty good.  I would consider two things:

- First I don't like the "internal" option here which leads to mixed return values.  Have you considered having `getSessionNameSpaceInternal()` which would call this method and extract the desired return value from the JsonResponse?
- Doing the above would allow you to directly return from catch block s like this:

  ```
  } catch (ClientException $e) {
      return new JsonResponse(
          'The endpoint responded with a ' . $e->getCode(),
          $e->getCode()
      );
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      return new JsonResponse( $e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode() );
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah mixed returns are not great and it makes sense (cleaner) to split that out into a concisely names method. Thanks :)